# About constructing a confidence bound using the minimum of iid exponential

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

The goal is to construct an upper bound for parameter $\theta$ given $X1,X2.. X10 \sim exponential (\theta)$ using some form of $y=Min(Xi's)$ as pivot.

I used $\frac{y}{\theta}$ as my pivot. This follows the distribution of the minimum of $\frac{Xi's}{\theta}$ which in turn are $\sim exponential(1)$, correct?

Comment: The $X_i/\theta$ are exponential with parameter $1$ if $\theta$ is a scale parameter rather than a rate parameter (you don't state your parameterization, so it's impossible to say whether you're correct). However the distribution of $y/\theta$ will not be the same as the distribution of $X_i/\theta$.

Comment: The $\theta$ is the scale parameter. Yes, $ y/\theta$ is not exponential (1). However, I can get the cdf of $y/\theta$ using the $xi/\theta$, yes?

Comment: Sure; it's pretty straightforward